# Setting up a custom login page with spring security woes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently trying to create a simple login with spring Security but am getting an error that I am assume is because of something I am doing wrong with resolver view or controller. Just can't seem to figure out what. I get the following error

"There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)"

My Config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    public void configureGlobal(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginpage")
                .permitAll().and()
                .logout();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    public void addViewController(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/loginpage").setViewName("loginpage");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class loginController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String homePage(Model model){

        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginpage")
    public String loginGetter(Model model){

        return "loginpage";
    }
}

Login page:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
Something is wrong
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
You have logged out
</div>
    <div>
        <form action="@{loginpage}" method="post">
            <div><label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></in></label></div>
            <div><label>Password: <input type="text" name="password"/></label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign in"/></in></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ronone</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecurityTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Added the pom file

Comment: can you declare the @Configuration annotation to your SecurityConfig class ?.

Comment: @georgesvan that was it, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ ...}
```

Annotating a class with the `@Configuration` indicates that the class can be used by the Spring IoC container as a source of bean definitions.